# PHP sliding window - how many occurrences for sum => X

Tags: php, sliding-window

I use this code

```
function maxSum($arr, $n, $k) 
{ 
    $show=[];  
    $max_sum = PHP_INT_MIN ; 

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $n - $k + 1; $i++) 
    { 
        $current_sum = 0; 
        for ( $j = 0; $j < $k; $j++) 
            $current_sum = $current_sum +  
                            $arr[$i + $j]; 

        $max_sum = max($current_sum, $max_sum ); 
        array_push($show,$max_sum);

    } 

    return $show; 
} 

    $arr = array(1, 4, 2, 10, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2); 
    $k = 3; 
    $n = count($arr); 

    print_r(maxSum($arr, $n, $k));
```

It works fine to find sums of 3 array items. Now I would like to do the opposite - to find how many array items should I sum to get 10 or close to 10.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: your code seems not working properly.:- https://3v4l.org/sYJ7B  . It needs to be `14,15,6,4,3` after first `16` of the final array

Comment: This code works fine for its purpose which is to count 3 array items together. Now I would like to use different approach to find out how many array items are needed to be sum together to get 10 while using sliding window.